# Smart Target using DD4T.NET

Tags: dd4t, 2013-sp1, smarttarget

I am creating DD4T.net page using Smart Target as per details mentioned in [Help Link](http://www.tridiondeveloper.com/dd4t-and-sdl-smarttarget-2014-integration) there is one method in view is called `@Html.RenderSmartTargetRegion("HomepagePromotions")` which is not available when I am trying to call I believe some DLL is missing.

Any Help regarding the same will be highly appreciated

Comment: can you edit your question and supply a bit more detail on what error you are getting?

Comment: @Html.RenderSmartTargetRegion("HomepagePromotions") method is not available and there is no error just method is missing.

Answer (score 4):

This function is not a standard functionality that is available in the dd4t dlls, that's why it doesn't work with your setup.

The blog post you refer to describes how you can add such functionality.
Basically, you should copy/paste the helper code  (class : SmartTargetHelper) in your own project, build it, and then calling the function RenderSmartTargetRegion should work.

Comment: I did exactly the same copy the class from the blog post in my .net application but the method is not available

Comment: Also there is not such function exist in that class

Comment: The function you describe is a c# extension method. Are you sure you added the function in a static class. Also, do you import that namespace in your razor view (@using "namespace" in top of your view ?)

Comment: Yes but RenderSmartTargetRegion is not available